# How to pass model from view to controller when click button in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

**Index - View**

```
@model SendAFaxWeb.Models.Send
//view start here
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Test Upload File</h2>
        <form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fax Number:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Recipients[0].Number)
             </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select File:</label>
                <input type="file" name="files" id="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="this.form.submit();" />
            </div>

            <div>
              @if (Model != null)
                 {
                   foreach (var item in Model.Documents)
                    {
                       <li>FileName: @item.Name</li>
                    }
                  }
             </div>
    </form>

    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" id="btnSend" />

    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript- the javascript doesnt work**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#btnSend").click(function () {
        alert("button click");
        e.preventDefault();

        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '@Url.Action("Send", "Home")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ contact: model }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Send(Send contact)
{
    //some code here
}
```

> I tried to pass model by using javascript to the controller, but its
>   not working. The alert in javascript also not popup. Can any one tell
>   me what wrong with the code.

Comment: Have you applied the HttpPost attribute onto the controller action? I ask as your JavaScript is doing a post and the default behavior of an action without an attribute is to accept only GET requests.

Comment: There are multiple errors. If the alert is not shown, then check your browser console for errors (do you have jquery loaded?). `e.preventDefault();` does nothing because there is no `e` (it needs to be `$("#btnSend").click(function (e) {` if you want to cancel the submit event). `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` is the original model (not what has been edited) so you script is pointless - your would be just sending back what the controller just sent

Comment: @StephenMuecke i already remove the `e.preventDefailt();` I what to post the one that has been edit actually. I check on browser console theres an error `localhost/:69 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. how can i overcome this problem?

Comment: It means you have not loaded `jquery-{version}.js` in your view (and you cannot remove `e.preventDefailt();` - it means you would be submitting the form twice - once by the normal submit and again by ajax.

Comment: yaaa youre right! i forgot to load `jquery.js`. Now the alert is working, but the post action to controller still not working. the console error is `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`, `Uncaught ReferenceError: Model is not defined`

Comment: Read my previous comments. What are you trying to do? Why in the world do you want to pass the the original model unchanged back to the server that just sent it? What do you really want to send to the `Send()` method?

Comment: First, During upload files, files and fax number will post to `"@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"`. It will return back the `Documents` which contains **files name & path** and the `Recipients` contains **fax number** in `Models.Send`. Then click `Send` button, the model that contains data will post to `@Url.Action("Send", "Home")` by using javascript. The problem is, im not able to pass the model to `Send` action. Sorry for my bad English and explanation. I need to solve this problem desperately. @Stephen Muecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke hope you can understand what im trying to do.

Comment: I have seen your previous questions on this. Why on earth are you not just making one submit. Why do you think you need to make a normal submit and then a separate ajax submit? Just do everything in one action.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Theres some reason why im not doing that way. In `Send` action have API that required the model detail to process. In the `Index` is just to get the details of files uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the below code

```
@model PK.LifeStyles.Web.Models.Reimbursement //model declaration on top

<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName",Model)'">
```

Your code behind  should look something like this

```
    public ActionResult Save(Reimbursement data)
    {
      // your  code
    }
   //just some random class
   public class Reimbursement{
         public string Destination { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have implemented cross origin security like : **@Html.AntiForgeryToken()**.
So you have to pass that value as **parameter** in your **AJAX** call as below.

**AJAX:**

```
data:{__RequestVerificationToken:$('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();}
```

Also you have to add attribute in **controller**.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Send(Send contact)
```

Comment: That's a side issue, and not the reason his code doesn't work.

Comment: you are right, at first look i see @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in code, so i have provide solution to overcome with it

Answer (score 0):

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("actionmethod", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
```

you can use this in view to send data from view to the controller