# ASP.NET MVC 5 Deleting Row in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I just want to enlighten on the behavior of my javascript and `Action` in my `Controller`. Currently, I have the below codes.

**Index.chtml**

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebSensoryMvc.Models.SessionData>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SessionName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EvaluationDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SessionNumber)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Active)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SessionName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EvaluationDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SessionNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" id=@item.SessionID data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "SessionData", new { id=item.SessionID })" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Details"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a>
                        <a href="#" onclick="deleteSession(@item.SessionID)" id="btnDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

    function deleteSession(sessionId) {
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Session Id " + sessionId + "?", function (result) {
            var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "SessionData")",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: sessionId, __RequestVerificationToken: token },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

**JavaScript under Index.chtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function deleteSession(sessionId) {
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete Session Id " + sessionId + "?", function (result) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "SessionData")",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: sessionId },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

**SessionDataController**

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        SessionData sessionData = db.SessionDatas.Find(id);
        if (sessionData == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(sessionData);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        SessionData sessionData = db.SessionDatas.Find(id);
        db.SessionDatas.Remove(sessionData);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

What I'm trying to do here is to delete a record using `jQuery` and skip the approach generated by MVC where when you click the Delete link, it will redirect you first to another View like a confirmation before it will totally delete the record in the database.

The strange behavior that I encountered when clicking the delete link using jQuery is that, when data annotation `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is present in `DeleteConfirm` action, my javascript and action is not executed or fired. But, when I remove `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` it executes my javascript and action. Anyone who can enlighten me on this?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, is for cross origin security.

you have to also add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in html and pass token **parameter value in AJAX Call** to successfully execute action with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute.

Please look it for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893962/6606630

Comment: Hi Sandip Patel,

So your suggesting I will wrap my chtml in a form?
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <div>...</div>
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching? There are many answers to this question...

It is expected behavior to prevent Cross-site request forgery. You would need to include the value from;

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

In your call to avoid this. 
Maybe read up on this;

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/