# I am doing a validation of username and password but it not working in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index(Models.boss ob)
{
    ViewBag.Bid = new SelectList(db.bosses, "Bid", "username");
     var mm = db.bosses.Any(model => model.username == ob.username && model.password == ob.password);
     if (mm)
     {
         return RedirectToAction("welcome");
     }
     else
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
     }
     return View(ob);
 }
```

this is my Index.View In that i validate every thing but is displaying as same on web page like this

> Login failed. Check your login details. Login data is incorrect!

so what did I do wrong?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed. Check your login details.");
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.username)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.username)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.username)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, "password=*")
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>SELECT USER</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("boss", ViewBag.Bid as SelectList, "Select a User", new { id = "boss" })
    </div>
    <button>LOGIN</button>
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed. Check your login details.");`? - it should be just `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`. And why do you have `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.username)` twice? And `@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, "password=*")` makes no sense - its needs to be just `@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password)`

Answer (score 0):

**Server side error** : `"Login data is incorrect!"`, which is written in controller.
**Client side** you have already set initial error `"Login failed. Check your login details."` in ValidationSummary.

Please remove initial client side validation message.

You have to also pass **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]** token parameter in action call.

Please look it for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893962/6606630