# Ajax call only from the same web application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-ajax

Is there a reliable way to check that incoming ajax calls that map to action methods in a ASP.NET MVC controller are made only by the web application itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **AntiforgeryToken** to validate AJAX call from web application itself, you can also use attribute to achive functionality.

**Please Refer :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/38893962/6606630

Comment: Thanks, i did not know the antiforgery token can be used also with ajax methods.